# Cannot get full JSON string, Its ends at

Tags: android

p

```
ackage com;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import bb.mobrep.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class JSONActivity extends Activity {

    public String readJSONFeed(String URL) {

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    Log.w("str", line.toString());
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("JSON", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    private class ReadJSONFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            return readJSONFeed(urls[0]);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                Log.i("JSON", "Number of surveys in feed: " + jsonArray.length());
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), jsonArray.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // ---print out the content of the json feed---
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    // jsonObject.getString("text") +
                    // " - " + jsonObject.getString("created_at"),
                    // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.jjson);

        new ReadJSONFeedTask().execute("http://220.247.247.130/b.txt");
    }
}
```

**Cannot get full string, Its ends at "C00000047",""nam.** Can somebody help me please 
but this  `http://220.247.247.130/c.txt`  file works fine.
how can I download lengthy JSON file and display

JSON:

```
{
"customers": [
    {
        "id": "C0000002",
        "nam": "Asian Pharmacy",
        "add": "125 Main Street Kattankudy "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000003",
        "nam": "Asiri Pharmaceuticals",
        "add": "213 Galahitiyawa Ganemulla aa"
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000004",
        "nam": "Badulla Apothecaries",
        "add": "229 Lower Street Badulla. "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000005",
        "nam": "B-Line Pharma",
        "add": "Carmel Estate Ibbagamuwa  "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000006",
        "nam": "A.K.I. ABEYRATHNA",
        "add": "47/K/18 SRI WICKRAMA MW SAMMANTHRANA PURA COLOMBO-15"
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000007",
        "nam": "Chamee Chemist",
        "add": "41275 Magalegoda Veyangoda. "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000008",
        "nam": "Chamee Pharmaceuticals (Pvt) Ltd",
        "add": "561/28 New Bus Stand Anuradhapura "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000009",
        "nam": "Chandrasiri Chemists",
        "add": "279B Morris Road Maitipe Galle."
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000010",
        "nam": "CHL Pharmaceuticals",
        "add": "41 E Railway Avenue Nugegoda. "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000011",
        "nam": "City Medicals",
        "add": "487 Hospital Road Jaffna "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000012",
        "nam": "City Medicals",
        "add": "433 Dockyard Road Trincomalee. "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000013",
        "nam": "Crystal Drugs",
        "add": "3 Donald Janz Road Bataganwila Galle."
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000014",
        "nam": "Crystal Pharmaceuticals",
        "add": "362/1 Dangedara Galle. "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000015",
        "nam": "Damith Distributors",
        "add": "275/5 1st Lane Mandawila Road Kesbewa Piliyandala."
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000016",
        "nam": "Galle Drug Stores",
        "add": "14 Ambagamuwa Road Gampola "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000017",
        "nam": "Gamage Distributors",
        "add": "217/C Jaya Mawatha Kadawatha. "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000018",
        "nam": "H.G. Pharmaceuticals",
        "add": "24 1st Cross Street Talbet Town Galle."
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000019",
        "nam": "Ishini Pharmaceuticals",
        "add": "104/6A Templers Road Mt. Lavinia. "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000020",
        "nam": "Kandy Medicals",
        "add": "41282 Market Road Mawanella. "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000021",
        "nam": "Kurunegala Medicals",
        "add": "4 Weavers Shopping Complex Mihindu Mawatha Kurunegala."
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000022",
        "nam": "Lloyed Pharmacy",
        "add": "1A Anagarika Dharmapala Mawatha Medagoda Matara."
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000023",
        "nam": "M.D.J. Distributors",
        "add": "21 St. Joseph's Road Nugegoda. "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000024",
        "nam": "Medicare Enterprises",
        "add": "394/6 Biyagama Road Gonawala Kelaniya."
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000025",
        "nam": "Mowlana Pharmacy",
        "add": "52 Main Street Kalmunai. "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000026",
        "nam": "Nanda Pharmacy",
        "add": "2 Fort Road Chilaw. "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000027",
        "nam": "Neelan Pharmaceuticals (Pvt) Ltd",
        "add": "Jaffna Road   Kilinochchi"
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000028",
        "nam": "New Eleans Marketing",
        "add": "110 Town Mosque Road Akkaraipattu. "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000029",
        "nam": "New Lanka Pharmacy",
        "add": "280 Galle Road Aluthgama. "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000030",
        "nam": "Noor Pharmaceuticals Pvt Ltd",
        "add": "50 Main Street Kalmunai. "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000031",
        "nam": "Pharmaco (Pvt) Ltd",
        "add": "77 Main Street Negombo "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000032",
        "nam": "Raaj Medicals Stores",
        "add": "91 Kandy Road Vavuniya. "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000033",
        "nam": "Ragama Pharmacy",
        "add": "34 Tewatte Road Ragama. "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000034",
        "nam": "Ransika Distributors",
        "add": "151/11 Tewatta Road Ragama "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000035",
        "nam": "SAS Pharmaceuticals",
        "add": "Pahala Ranawana Dewalegama.  "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000036",
        "nam": "Sathsara Enterprises",
        "add": "495 Mihindu Mawatha Pitipana North Homagama."
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000037",
        "nam": "Sigma Impex",
        "add": "933 Maradana Road Colombo 08. "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000038",
        "nam": "Southern Pharmaceuticals (Pvt) Ltd",
        "add": "1605/32 Crystal Terrace Malabe Road Kottawa  Pannipitiya"
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000039",
        "nam": "Sri Lanka Pharmacy (Pvt) Ltd",
        "add": "39 D S Senanayake Veediya Kandy. "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000040",
        "nam": "Supreme Pharmaceutical Care Distributors",
        "add": "30/81 Ramya Gardens Kalapaluwawa Rajagiriya."
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000041",
        "nam": "T.C. Distributors",
        "add": "315 Galle Road Mt. Lavinia. "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000042",
        "nam": "The New Pharmacy",
        "add": "85A Kandy Road Kurunegala. "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000043",
        "nam": "Thusitha Distributors & Pharmacy",
        "add": "64 Central Street Hingurakgoda "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000044",
        "nam": "United Pharma (Pvt) Ltd",
        "add": "18 Havelock Place Galle. "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000045",
        "nam": "United Pharmacy",
        "add": "429/A Pita Kotte Kotte. "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000046",
        "nam": "Viththy Med Engineering",
        "add": "22 A St. Anthanys Road Batticaloa. "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000047",
        "nam": "Wettasinghe Pharmaceuticals",
        "add": "86 Uyana Road Moratuwa. "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000048",
        "nam": "Wickramasooriya Enterprises",
        "add": "Carmel Estate Bakmeegolla Ibbagamuwa "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000049",
        "nam": "Wijemanne Grocers",
        "add": "43 Main Street Horana. "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000078",
        "nam": "1a",
        "add": "2b 3c 4d 5e"
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000079",
        "nam": "dd",
        "add": "dd dd dd "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000080",
        "nam": "saliya",
        "add": "add1  add 2 add 3 add 4 "
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000081",
        "nam": "wasim mirza",
        "add": "a11 a22 a33 a44"
    },
    {
        "id": "C0000082",
        "nam": "tharindu",
        "add": "   "
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Why are you using jsonArray not JsonObject ?

Comment: Hum! How it should be can you explain it bit please.

Comment: see my answer. it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string is a JSONOBject.

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
           // Log.i("JSON", "Number of surveys in feed: " + jsonArray.length());
            JSONArray ja = jsonObject.getJSONArray("customers");
           // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, jsonArray.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // ---print out the content of the json feed---
            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jb = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                String s = jb.getString("id");
                Log.i("ID is ",s);
                String nam = jb.getString("nam");
                Log.i("Nam is",nam);
                String add = jb.getString("add");
                Log.i("Add is",add);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Your `doInbackground`. Declare String _response as a class variable.

```
       protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                 _response=EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            }
           }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return _response;
    }
```

Edit:

`{` represents json object node

`[` represetns json array node.

```
{  // your string is a json object    
"customers": [   // json array of customers
{                // json object
    "id": "C0000002"  // json id is string
```

I just tried it out. This is what i get.

```
07-13 08:29:26.239: I/ID is(1571): C0000002
07-13 08:29:26.239: I/Nam is(1571): Asian Pharmacy
07-13 08:29:26.239: I/Add is(1571): 125 Main Street Kattankudy 
07-13 08:29:26.239: I/ID is(1571): C0000003
07-13 08:29:26.239: I/Nam is(1571): Asiri Pharmaceuticals
07-13 08:29:26.249: I/Add is(1571): 213 Galahitiyawa Ganemulla aa
07-13 08:29:26.249: I/ID is(1571): C0000004
07-13 08:29:26.259: I/Nam is(1571): Badulla Apothecaries
07-13 08:29:26.259: I/Add is(1571): 229 Lower Street Badulla. 
07-13 08:29:26.259: I/ID is(1571): C0000005
07-13 08:29:26.259: I/Nam is(1571): B-Line Pharma
07-13 08:29:26.259: I/Add is(1571): Carmel Estate Ibbagamuwa  
07-13 08:29:26.259: I/ID is(1571): C0000006
07-13 08:29:26.259: I/Nam is(1571): A.K.I. ABEYRATHNA
07-13 08:29:26.259: I/Add is(1571): 47/K/18 SRI WICKRAMA MW SAMMANTHRANA PURA COLOMBO-15
07-13 08:29:26.259: I/ID is(1571): C0000007
07-13 08:29:26.269: I/Nam is(1571): Chamee Chemist
07-13 08:29:26.269: I/Add is(1571): 41275 Magalegoda Veyangoda. 
07-13 08:29:26.269: I/ID is(1571): C0000008
07-13 08:29:26.269: I/Nam is(1571): Chamee Pharmaceuticals (Pvt) Ltd
07-13 08:29:26.269: I/Add is(1571): 561/28 New Bus Stand Anuradhapura 
07-13 08:29:26.269: I/ID is(1571): C0000009
07-13 08:29:26.269: I/Nam is(1571): Chandrasiri Chemists
07-13 08:29:26.269: I/Add is(1571): 279B Morris Road Maitipe Galle.
07-13 08:29:26.269: I/ID is(1571): C0000010
07-13 08:29:26.269: I/Nam is(1571): CHL Pharmaceuticals
07-13 08:29:26.279: I/Add is(1571): 41 E Railway Avenue Nugegoda. 
07-13 08:29:26.309: I/ID is(1571): C0000011
07-13 08:29:26.309: I/Nam is(1571): City Medicals
07-13 08:29:26.309: I/Add is(1571): 487 Hospital Road Jaffna 
07-13 08:29:26.309: I/ID is(1571): C0000012
07-13 08:29:26.309: I/Nam is(1571): City Medicals
07-13 08:29:26.309: I/Add is(1571): 433 Dockyard Road Trincomalee. 
07-13 08:29:26.320: I/ID is(1571): C0000013
07-13 08:29:26.320: I/Nam is(1571): Crystal Drugs
07-13 08:29:26.320: I/Add is(1571): 3 Donald Janz Road Bataganwila Galle.
07-13 08:29:26.320: I/ID is(1571): C0000014
07-13 08:29:26.320: I/Nam is(1571): Crystal Pharmaceuticals
07-13 08:29:26.320: I/Add is(1571): 362/1 Dangedara Galle. 
07-13 08:29:26.329: I/ID is(1571): C0000015
07-13 08:29:26.329: I/Nam is(1571): Damith Distributors
07-13 08:29:26.329: I/Add is(1571): 275/5 1st Lane Mandawila Road Kesbewa Piliyandala.
07-13 08:29:26.339: I/ID is(1571): C0000016
07-13 08:29:26.339: I/Nam is(1571): Galle Drug Stores
07-13 08:29:26.339: I/Add is(1571): 14 Ambagamuwa Road Gampola 
07-13 08:29:26.339: I/ID is(1571): C0000017
07-13 08:29:26.339: I/Nam is(1571): Gamage Distributors
07-13 08:29:26.339: I/Add is(1571): 217/C Jaya Mawatha Kadawatha. 
07-13 08:29:26.339: I/ID is(1571): C0000018
07-13 08:29:26.349: I/Nam is(1571): H.G. Pharmaceuticals
07-13 08:29:26.349: I/Add is(1571): 24 1st Cross Street Talbet Town Galle.
07-13 08:29:26.349: I/ID is(1571): C0000019
07-13 08:29:26.349: I/Nam is(1571): Ishini Pharmaceuticals
07-13 08:29:26.349: I/Add is(1571): 104/6A Templers Road Mt. Lavinia. 
07-13 08:29:26.349: I/ID is(1571): C0000020
07-13 08:29:26.359: I/Nam is(1571): Kandy Medicals
07-13 08:29:26.359: I/Add is(1571): 41282 Market Road Mawanella. 
07-13 08:29:26.359: I/ID is(1571): C0000021
07-13 08:29:26.369: D/dalvikvm(1571): GC_CONCURRENT freed 149K, 10% free 2663K/2932K, paused 6ms+53ms, total 190ms
07-13 08:29:26.379: I/Nam is(1571): Kurunegala Medicals
07-13 08:29:26.379: I/Add is(1571): 4 Weavers Shopping Complex Mihindu Mawatha Kurunegala.
07-13 08:29:26.379: I/ID is(1571): C0000022
07-13 08:29:26.379: I/Nam is(1571): Lloyed Pharmacy
07-13 08:29:26.391: I/Add is(1571): 1A Anagarika Dharmapala Mawatha Medagoda Matara.
07-13 08:29:26.391: I/ID is(1571): C0000023
07-13 08:29:26.391: I/Nam is(1571): M.D.J. Distributors
07-13 08:29:26.391: I/Add is(1571): 21 St. Josephs Road Nugegoda. 
07-13 08:29:26.391: I/ID is(1571): C0000024
07-13 08:29:26.391: I/Nam is(1571): Medicare Enterprises
07-13 08:29:26.391: I/Add is(1571): 394/6 Biyagama Road Gonawala Kelaniya.
07-13 08:29:26.399: I/ID is(1571): C0000025
07-13 08:29:26.399: I/Nam is(1571): Mowlana Pharmacy
07-13 08:29:26.399: I/Add is(1571): 52 Main Street Kalmunai. 
07-13 08:29:26.399: I/ID is(1571): C0000026
07-13 08:29:26.399: I/Nam is(1571): Nanda Pharmacy
07-13 08:29:26.409: I/Add is(1571): 2 Fort Road Chilaw. 
07-13 08:29:26.409: I/ID is(1571): C0000027
07-13 08:29:26.409: I/Nam is(1571): Neelan Pharmaceuticals (Pvt) Ltd
07-13 08:29:26.419: I/Add is(1571): Jaffna Road   Kilinochchi
07-13 08:29:26.419: I/ID is(1571): C0000028
07-13 08:29:26.429: I/Nam is(1571): New Eleans Marketing
07-13 08:29:26.429: I/Add is(1571): 110 Town Mosque Road Akkaraipattu. 
07-13 08:29:26.429: I/ID is(1571): C0000029
07-13 08:29:26.429: I/Nam is(1571): New Lanka Pharmacy
07-13 08:29:26.429: I/Add is(1571): 280 Galle Road Aluthgama. 
07-13 08:29:26.429: I/ID is(1571): C0000030
07-13 08:29:26.429: I/Nam is(1571): Noor Pharmaceuticals Pvt Ltd
07-13 08:29:26.429: I/Add is(1571): 50 Main Street Kalmunai. 
07-13 08:29:26.439: I/ID is(1571): C0000031
07-13 08:29:26.439: I/Nam is(1571): Pharmaco (Pvt) Ltd
07-13 08:29:26.439: I/Add is(1571): 77 Main Street Negombo 
07-13 08:29:26.439: I/ID is(1571): C0000032
07-13 08:29:26.439: I/Nam is(1571): Raaj Medicals Stores
07-13 08:29:26.439: I/Add is(1571): 91 Kandy Road Vavuniya. 
07-13 08:29:26.439: I/ID is(1571): C0000033
07-13 08:29:26.449: I/Nam is(1571): Ragama Pharmacy
07-13 08:29:26.449: I/Add is(1571): 34 Tewatte Road Ragama. 
07-13 08:29:26.449: I/ID is(1571): C0000034
07-13 08:29:26.449: I/Nam is(1571): Ransika Distributors
07-13 08:29:26.449: I/Add is(1571): 151/11 Tewatta Road Ragama 
07-13 08:29:26.449: I/ID is(1571): C0000035
07-13 08:29:26.449: I/Nam is(1571): SAS Pharmaceuticals
07-13 08:29:26.449: I/Add is(1571): Pahala Ranawana Dewalegama.  
07-13 08:29:26.449: I/ID is(1571): C0000036
07-13 08:29:26.459: I/Nam is(1571): Sathsara Enterprises
07-13 08:29:26.459: I/Add is(1571): 495 Mihindu Mawatha Pitipana North Homagama.
07-13 08:29:26.459: I/ID is(1571): C0000037
07-13 08:29:26.459: I/Nam is(1571): Sigma Impex
07-13 08:29:26.459: I/Add is(1571): 933 Maradana Road Colombo 08. 
07-13 08:29:26.459: I/ID is(1571): C0000038
07-13 08:29:26.469: I/Nam is(1571): Southern Pharmaceuticals (Pvt) Ltd
07-13 08:29:26.469: I/Add is(1571): 1605/32 Crystal Terrace Malabe Road Kottawa  Pannipitiya
07-13 08:29:26.469: I/ID is(1571): C0000039
07-13 08:29:26.469: I/Nam is(1571): Sri Lanka Pharmacy (Pvt) Ltd
07-13 08:29:26.469: I/Add is(1571): 39 D S Senanayake Veediya Kandy. 
07-13 08:29:26.469: I/ID is(1571): C0000040
07-13 08:29:26.481: I/Nam is(1571): Supreme Pharmaceutical Care Distributors
07-13 08:29:26.481: I/Add is(1571): 30/81 Ramya Gardens Kalapaluwawa Rajagiriya.
07-13 08:29:26.481: I/ID is(1571): C0000041
07-13 08:29:26.489: I/Nam is(1571): T.C. Distributors
07-13 08:29:26.489: I/Add is(1571): 315 Galle Road Mt. Lavinia. 
07-13 08:29:26.489: I/ID is(1571): C0000042
07-13 08:29:26.489: I/Nam is(1571): The New Pharmacy
07-13 08:29:26.489: I/Add is(1571): 85A Kandy Road Kurunegala. 
07-13 08:29:26.489: I/ID is(1571): C0000043
07-13 08:29:26.489: I/Nam is(1571): Thusitha Distributors & Pharmacy
07-13 08:29:26.499: I/Add is(1571): 64 Central Street Hingurakgoda 
07-13 08:29:26.499: I/ID is(1571): C0000044
07-13 08:29:26.499: I/Nam is(1571): United Pharma (Pvt) Ltd
07-13 08:29:26.499: I/Add is(1571): 18 Havelock Place Galle. 
07-13 08:29:26.499: I/ID is(1571): C0000045
07-13 08:29:26.499: I/Nam is(1571): United Pharmacy
07-13 08:29:26.499: I/Add is(1571): 429/A Pita Kotte Kotte. 
07-13 08:29:26.499: I/ID is(1571): C0000046
07-13 08:29:26.499: I/Nam is(1571): Viththy Med Engineering
07-13 08:29:26.509: I/Add is(1571): 22 A St. Anthanys Road Batticaloa. 
07-13 08:29:26.509: I/ID is(1571): C0000047
07-13 08:29:26.509: I/Nam is(1571): Wettasinghe Pharmaceuticals
07-13 08:29:26.509: I/Add is(1571): 86 Uyana Road Moratuwa. 
07-13 08:29:26.519: I/ID is(1571): C0000048
07-13 08:29:26.519: I/Nam is(1571): Wickramasooriya Enterprises
07-13 08:29:26.519: I/Add is(1571): Carmel Estate Bakmeegolla Ibbagamuwa 
07-13 08:29:26.519: I/ID is(1571): C0000049
07-13 08:29:26.519: I/Nam is(1571): Wijemanne Grocers
07-13 08:29:26.519: I/Add is(1571): 43 Main Street Horana. 
07-13 08:29:26.519: I/ID is(1571): C0000078
07-13 08:29:26.519: I/Nam is(1571): 1a
07-13 08:29:26.519: I/Add is(1571): 2b 3c 4d 5e
07-13 08:29:26.519: I/ID is(1571): C0000079
07-13 08:29:26.519: I/Nam is(1571): dd
07-13 08:29:26.519: I/Add is(1571): dd dd dd 
07-13 08:29:26.529: I/ID is(1571): C0000080
07-13 08:29:26.529: I/Nam is(1571): saliya
07-13 08:29:26.529: I/Add is(1571): add1  add 2 add 3 add 4 
07-13 08:29:26.529: I/ID is(1571): C0000081
07-13 08:29:26.529: I/Nam is(1571): wasim mirza
07-13 08:29:26.529: I/Add is(1571): a11 a22 a33 a44
07-13 08:29:26.539: I/ID is(1571): C0000082
07-13 08:29:26.539: I/Nam is(1571): tharindu
07-13 08:29:26.539: I/Add is(1571):
```

Comment: Dear Raghunandan,
I did not get the full string at **Log.w("str", line.toString());**

Comment: @user2578674 will look into it but `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result)` your result is a json object.

Comment: @user2578674 you will not see everything in log. but you can see the parsed result check it. the above works

Comment: @user2578674 i guess there is a limit on the numbers of lines for a single log. I read it somewhere on stackoverflow. I can't recall exactly. If i can get the link i will post it here.

Comment: Thank you Guys! Now it works, Hum! there is a limit on the numbers  lines for a single log

Answer (score 0):

Cast String into JsonObject

```
JSONObject jObj = null;

 jObj = new JSONObject(json);

System.out.print(jObj.toString());
```

You can then user to .get method on JSONObject to retreive object values like

```
jObj.get('nameofyourvariable');
```

P.S. json should be string, a json string.